# How do I mock a 'timeout' or 'failure' response using Sinon / Qunit?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jquery, qunit, sinon

I've had no problems sorting out mocking the success condition, but cannot seem to fathom how to mock the failure/timeout conditions when using **Sinon** and **Qunit** to test and ajax function:

My set up is this:

```
$(document).ready( function() {

    module( "myTests", {
        setup: function() {
            xhr = sinon.sandbox.useFakeXMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.requests = [];
            xhr.onCreate = function (request) {
                xhr.requests.push(request);
            };

            myObj = new MyObj("#elemSelector");
        },
        teardown: function() {
            myObj.destroy();
            xhr.restore();
        }
    });
});
```

and my success case test, running happily and receiving/passing through the received data to the success method is this:

```js
test("The data fetch method reacts correctly to receiving data",
    function () {
        sinon.spy(MyObject.prototype, "ajaxSuccess");

        MyObject.prototype.fetchData();

        //check a call got heard
        equal(1, xhr.requests.length);

        //return a success method for that obj
        xhr.requests[0].respond(200, {
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            },
            '[{ "responseData": "some test data" }]'
        );
        //check the correct success method was called
        ok(MyObj.prototype.ajaxSuccess.calledOnce);

        MyObj.prototype.ajaxSuccess.restore();
    }
);
```

However, I cannot work out what I should be putting instead of this:

```
xhr.requests[0].respond(200, { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
                '[{ "responseData": "some test data" }]');
```

to make my ajax call handler `hear` a failure or timeout method? The only thing I could think to try was this:

```
xhr.requests[0].respond(408);
```

But it doesn't work.

What am I doing wrong or what have I misunderstood? All help much appreciated :)

Comment: Timeout is a lack of response in given time, so you can't return a timeout

Comment: I was hoping sinon might overcome that and give a standardised interface for all types of response.  If I cannot 'return' a timeout using sinon - then how do I fake one?

Comment: I don't know sinon so maybe there's something specific, but normally you set the timeout to say 1ms, and use wait on server or mock-server side.

Comment: Good idea - I'll try that for the timeout method, but how about the failure method, what would the standard sinon way be of doing that?

Answer (score 1):

For the timeout, sinon’s [fake timers](http://sinonjs.org/docs/#clock) could help. Using them you wouldn’t need to set the timeout to 1ms. As for the failures, your approach [looks correct](http://sinonjs.org/docs/#respond) to me. Can you give us more code, especially the failure handler?

Answer (score 0):

Doing something like this

```
requests[0].respond(
        404,
        {
            'Content-Type': 'text/plain',
            'Content-Length': 14
        },
        'File not found'
);
```

works to trigger the 'error' callback in jQuery AJAX requests.

As for the timouts, you can use sinons fake clock like this:

```
test('timeout-test', function() {
    var clock = sinon.useFakeTimers();
    var errorCallback = sinon.spy();

    jQuery.ajax({
        url: '/foobar.php',
        data: 'some data',
        error: errorCallback,
        timeout: 20000 // 20 seconds
    });

    // Advance 19 seconds in time
    clock.tick(19000);

    strictEqual(errorCallback.callCount, 0, 'error callback was not called before timeout');

    // Advance another 2 seconds in time
    clock.tick(2000);

    strictEqual(errorCallback.callCount, 1, 'error callback was called once after timeout');
});
```

Comment: Perhaps the way to go for jQuery's Ajax, but CJ was asking about sinon's fake XHR; neither of these approaches work for sinon.

Answer (score 0):

The main idea that I would use is to wrap everything related to the request inside "another function" that returns a promise.

Then in the test, when I mock the "another function" I just return a Promise.reject({}).

If some endpoint is going to give me a timeout, that is equivalent to a failed promise.

Answer (score -1):

Set a timeout on your [$.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) call and use Sinon [fake timers](http://sinonjs.org/docs/#clock) to move the clock ahead before responding.

Comment: CJ isn't making a $.ajax() call, but a sinon fake XHR call and sinon doesn't support the .timeout property.